# Why I cannot edit project started on another pc?

Tags: django

I have created a project on one pc and I want to work on it from second pc. I ziped the project from one pc and opened it from another. When I make changes for example in models and want to makemigrations it shows that no changes have been made. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Not all changes in models need migrations. For example adding extra properties do not require migrating the database. Anyway, right now the question can not be answered, since too much is unknown. Furthermore I strongly advise you to use a subversioning system like `git` instead of copying files between systems.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for your answer. I'm using git, just this time made an exception. Is there any seetings in project (In general) that must be changed when trying to open the same project on another pc ? Ofc not including particular libraries installed by pip

Comment: Also the problem is that I cannot edit anything in project. I can run the server and display everything but when I change the html content it does not update :(

Comment: Regarding your migrations problem, since you copied the whole project, you probably copied the migrations folder too. So that's why no change is being detected. You just have to run a `python manage.py migrate`